# Pygame KEYDOWN name error

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame, sys, pygame.mixer 

pygame.init()

size = width,height = 1256,640
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
player_x = 0
player_y = 0
movex = 0

maintheme = pygame.mixer.Sound("music/mainthemes.ogg")
maintheme.play()

player_w = pygame.image.load("characters/player/character_w.png").convert_alpha()
player_a = pygame.image.load("characters/player/character_a.png").convert_alpha()
player_s = pygame.image.load("characters/player/character_s.png").convert_alpha()
player_d = pygame.image.load("characters/player/character_d.png").convert_alpha()

background1 = pygame.image.load("maps/background1.png").convert_alpha()

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_a:
                movex=-1

        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        screen.blit(background1,(0,0))
        screen.blit(player_s,(player_x,player_y))

        pygame.display.update()
```

The error is this: 
  File "/home/fenton/Desktop/main.py", line 27, in 
    if event.type==KEYDOWN:
NameError: name 'KEYDOWN' is not defined
[Finished in 4.9s]

Answer (score 3):

You need to do:

```
if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
```

Otherwise, Python has no clue where `KEYDOWN` is defined.

---

Also, you may want to change it to:

```
elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
```

because there is no way `event.type` could be `pygame.QUIT` *and* `pygame.KEYDOWN`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from pygame.locals import *
```

Add this line and you're good to go.

However while this does work it is bad practice and the solution **iCodez** provided should be favored and used instead.

Comment: Usually it is considered a bad practice to do that.  It dumps a whole bunch of names in the global namespace that can easily be overwritten.

Comment: Stupid me I normally do that line at the start Houssni!

Comment: I'll echo what iCodez already said to make it clear that you should not do this.  It's poor practice.  Don't do it.

Comment: @ktodisco I agree to you both. I just wanted to add an alternative, but less good, answer. I myself just use iCodez solution though.

Comment: @Houssni Then you should make it clear in the answer that while it works, a better practice should be used.